# MS Power Query - eliminating duplicates in a set of delimited strings

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery

I have Excel data which looks something like this:

```
Sources   Targets   Routes

Lemons    Chair     A,D
Lemons    Chair     D,F
Oranges   Chair     B,F,G
Oranges   Chair     B,C
Oranges   Door      A,G
Oranges   Door      B,C
```

I am trying to use Power Query to condense it to this:

```
Sources   Targets   Routes

Lemons    Chair     A,D,F
Oranges   Chair     B,C,F,G
Oranges   Door      A,B,C,G
```

That is, for each Source/Target pair, I need to

- Split apart the comma-delimited Routes,

  Eliminate the duplicate routes

  Combine the routes back into a comma-delimited list

  Display it in a single record for the Source/Target pair.

There is a max of 3 routes in Routes source data. 
I'm pretty sure I need to split the Routes column into 3 columns, then use *Group*.  But there I get stuck.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below implements the steps you outlined plus a sort on Routes.
It doesn't use split columns, but Text.Split.

The SplittedRoutes step was created using some text transform function on the Transform tab, then adjusted to use Text.Split.

Likewise, the GroupedRows step was created with Group By on the Transform tab, using operation All Rows, then adjusted to the code below.

```
let
    Source = ExcelData,
    SplittedRoutes = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Routes", each Text.Split(_,",")}}),
    ExpandedRoutes = Table.ExpandListColumn(SplittedRoutes, "Routes"),
    RemovedDuplicates = Table.Distinct(ExpandedRoutes, {"Sources", "Targets", "Routes"}),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(RemovedDuplicates, {"Sources", "Targets"}, {{"Routes", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(_[Routes]),","), type text}})
in
    GroupedRows
```

Comment: MarcelBeug - Thanks.  That works, and I learned a lot by studying your answer.  One followup question - what does the underscore do in 
    List.Sort(_[Routes])
?

Comment: In this case _ represents the current row. _[Routes] gets the value in the Routes column from the current row. More generally, _ is the variable we are iterating over with the each statement. "each _" and "(x) => x" are equivalent when passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Apparently, in the particular context of Table.Group, the underscore is not required; it was included in the code generated by selecting operation "All Rows", so I left t in, but if it is removed, the code still works fine.